# Running Facenet using OpenVINO

Tags: python, tensorflow, openvino

I am stuck at a problem using OpenVINO. I am trying to run the facenet after converting model using OpenVINO toolkit but I am unable to use **.npy** and **.pickle** for complete face recognition. I am successful in converting **.pb** file to **.bin** and **.xml** file using OpenVino toolkit.

Answer (score 0):

openvino converts the model to intermediate representation, which is compatible across multiple hardwares. It can improve the performance of your model too. Since you have already mentioned that yopu were ableto convert your model to IR format, the next phase is inference for which you can use the .xml and .bin files.
Can you please state what exactly do you intend to carryout with .npy or .pickle files?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Python APIs to integrate OV inference into your Python application. Please see inference_engine/samples/python_samples folder for existing Python samples.